# NuGet targets wrong folder when publishing web application via MSBuild.exe in CI

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration, nuget, bamboo

I am trying to set up a project in our CI server (bamboo).

I have an API solution containing multiple projects (data access, service interfaces, WebApi, tests, a few others... you get the idea).  I run nuget.exe in a script to pull in the requisite packages at the solution level.  The packages go into the solution directory `.nuget`.

When I use MSBuild to create the binaries, everything is fine.  I then use the MSTest runner on the test projects; still everything is fine.  I then shut down the destination web service, and then run `msbuild.exe` against the WebApi project with the parameters `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=INTENV`.

This is where bamboo barks at me.  I get the failure error message like so:

```
error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\(My Solution Folder)\\.nuget\NuGet.targets.
```

The project is obviously looking for the dependencies in the project folder, in this case and in this case only.

How do I tell MSBuild.exe that this folder is one level up?  This is the only place where it gets confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what was happening when I targeted the project instead of the solution with MSBuild.exe is that it considered `$(SolutionDir)` to be the project directory.  It was looking for the the nuget targets at `$(SolutionDir).nuget\NuGet.targets`, which was an incorrect path if starting at the project level, but perfectly fine at the solution level.

On my MSBuild.exe command line, I added a parameter as follows:

```
/property:SolutionDir="(path of my solution)"
```

This did the trick.

I also tried to change the project settings, but NuGet always replaced them; the above manner is the only way I could get it to work.